# Argument list too long when using du

Tags: shell, disk-usage, sort

I've got a command to find big files in a particular folder but for some reason it won't work in certain situations and I get an "Argument list too long" error. How do I fix this command so it works every time?

```
jbsmith:/tmp$ sudo du -hsx * | sort -rh | head -10
-bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long
```

Answer (score 8):

You could replace that command with `find` instead of globbing and do it

```
sudo find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name "." -exec du -hsx {} + | sort -rh | head -10
```

assuming your `find` supports the `+` notation.

This will find everything under the current directory without descending deeper, and ignore the "." (thanks for that reminder @rudimeier!)

This will include all of the files in the current directory, like the glob you had originally.  Unlike that glob, this will also find files that start with `.` (unless you were playing with your shell options to enable `dotglob` already).

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: @JoelSmith what doesn't work about it?

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: @JoelSmith no errors or anything?  oh, I did get an order backwards, see my update

Answer (score 7):

I landed on this question while looking for a way to handle "argument list too long" with `du`. In my case I didn't want to filter the output but instead to get a total of all files that match a pattern. With the approaches in other questions I could not get a grand total as they end up calling `du` several times with a subset of arguments.

The solution was to use `--files0-from=` instead of passing filenames as arguments.

In the end this worked for me:

```
du -Lhsc --files0-from=<(find -L -maxdepth 2 \( -name "*.gz" -o -name "*.xz" \) -print0)
```

- `-L` follow symlinks both in finding and size calculation.
- `-c` get the cumulative total
- `<()` process substitution to create a `file` on the fly
- `-print0` to match `du`'s expectation
- `\( \)` to be able to use `-o` with two `-name` args

In the same way the answer to the above question could be:

```
du -hsx --files0-from=<(find -maxdepth 1 ! -name "." -print0) | sort -rh | head -10
```

Comment: I wish BSD du had `--files0-from=`, but unfortunately this only works with gnu du

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of GNU coreutils, you can use the [`--max-depth` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#index-_002dd-depth) instead of enumerating the files with `*`. This way you don't risk running into the command line length limit if there are too many files. There is no `--min-depth`, so the toplevel directory will be listed at the end.

```
du -x -d 1 | head -n -1 | sort -r | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that command lines are not unlimited in size and number of arguments. A common way to get around these limits it to use `find` / `xargs` pipes.

Your case should work like this:

```
 sudo sh -c "find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 |xargs -0 du -hsx -- " |sort -rh |head
```

`sudo` requirement makes it look a bit more tricky than usual.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Updated , regarding `sudo`. What else does not work?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo ls | sudo parallel -j1 du -hsx | sort -rh | head -10
```

Answer (score -1):

You can work around this with `find`, if you know the floor for the file size you want to see:

```
find /tmp -size 1G -type f
```

Comment: That's not what I want